# Regex replace everything not starting with multiple times in line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a parser of sorts in javascript that takes a mathematical expression given to the script as a string, and evaluates it and does some other things with it. If the users want to use builtin Javascript mathematical functions, they have to enter the following string e.g. "1 + Math.log(x)". That becomes very tedious when things get nested e.g "Math.abs(Math.log(Math.pow(x, 2))) + Math.log2(x)". As you can see, the "Math." part of it not only takes longer to write, but makes it less readable. I want to remove that "Math." part. The way I've done it is using simple regex that basically has a list of all Javascript Math constants and methods and simply prepends the "Math." part of it. Simple enough:

```
  input = input.replace(/(E|PI|SQRT2|SQRT1_2|LN2|LN10|LOG2E|LOG10E)/g, "Math.$1");
```

The same things happens for the methods. This works fine. But as always that's not very flexible and leaves room for misunderstanding and somebody may coma along and insist on typing Math.log(x) which will in turn be replaced with Math.Math.log(x), which won't work.

What I want to know is, is there some way to match any of these predefined strings (constants and methods) so that they will only be matched via regex if they don't have the "Math." part in front of it. I have tried this

```
^(?!Math\.)(log2|log|exp|abs)
```

but it is quite useless, as this doesn't work with nesting and even multiple operands. Is there any way to do this purely in regex, as this would make the entire process more elegant. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about just doing this first? `input.replace(/\bMath\./g,'')` Then do the regex that adds it.

Comment: What happens if a user comes along free-types in something not in your list? This is a very bad way to allow users enter their formula's. Unless you totally parse every last character for validity, I wouldn't do this. If your lazy, make a dropdown list of functions to and or operations they can pick from.

Comment: That would definitely work, but it wouldn't be very elegant, it seems cleaner to do it all within one line. The answer given does exactly what I wanted in a very clean way.

Comment: this particular script simply generates a URL that is used for some other parser. It has no effect on the outside world or has access to any data whatsoever. Whatever malicious code anyone might stick in there, the effect would be no different if they had simply opened their JS console and typed the malicious code there. Security is not an issue here, but I agree, evaluating raw input it generally bad practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following trick so that it gets replaced even if it matches or not:

```
(?:Math\.)?(log2|log|exp|abs|pow)
```

And replace with `Math.$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD9cK8/4)